# Removing duplicate collection strings in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I am working on a hypothetical question. One of them being that if there are duplicate string collections in memory, how would I get about removing the duplicates while maintaining the original order or the collections?

Comment: Your hypothetical question is quite vague. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Frédéric not sure how to elaborate. I was just thinking if there are duplicate collections, how would I go about removing duplicates.

Comment: You want to remove the duplicate collections, or duplicate items within the collections?

Comment: duplicate items within the collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
        List<String> stringlistone = new List<string>() { "Hello", "Hi" };
        List<String> stringlisttwo = new List<string>() { "Hi", "Bye" };
        IEnumerable<String> distinctList = stringlistone.Concat(stringlisttwo).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        List<List<String>> listofstringlist = new List<List<String>>() { stringlistone, stringlisttwo };
        IEnumerable<String> distinctlistofstringlist = listofstringlist.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

its depends on how you join the lists but it should give you a idea, added the ordinal ignore case in case you wanted the destinct list to treat "hi" and "Hi" as the same

you can also just call the distinct so if you did

```
        List<String> stringlistone = new List<string>() { "Hi", "Hello", "Hi" };

        stringlistone = stringlistone.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

stringlistone would be a list with `stringlistone[0] == "Hi"` and `stringlistone[1] == "Hello"`

Comment: The distinct keyword makes it really simple

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. Framework does not create duplicate string in memory. All pointers with same string value points to same location in memory.

Comment: can you provide a link to msdn so I can read more details on that?

Comment: @hungryMind, only literal strings are automatically interned, though.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `List<List<string>>` that you read from a file or database (so they're not already interned) and you want no duplicate strings, you can use this code:

```
public void FoldStrings(List<List<string>> stringCollections)
{
   var interned = new Dictionary<string,string> ();
   foreach (var stringCollection in stringCollections)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < stringCollection.Count; i++)
      {
         string str = stringCollection[i];
         string s;
         if (interned.TryGetValue (str, out s))
         {
            // We already have an instance of this string.
            stringCollection[i] = s;
         }
         else
         {
            // First time we've seen this string... add to hashtable.
            interned[str]=str;
         }
      }
   }
}
```